# Codeigniter redirect without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.4 with my WAMP. Everytime I set the `$config['index_page'] = ''`, codeigniter cannot find the controller method. When I set it back to `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'`, it can find the method again. I want to get rid of the `index.php` so that my ajax call can work correctly.

Here are my configuration files:

```
**.htaccess:**

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /mca-backend
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

**config.php**

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I have an class which redirect the request to another class method, and here is the code:

```
redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
```

This happens when the redirection code gets called and I am pretty sure the `rewrite_module` on my WAMP apache is on.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can do this without htaccess just using site_url in place of base_url wherever you are using redirection

Comment: You want to add index.php in your URL at redirect time?

Comment: Hi, Mitul. No. I want to get rid of it. But if I get rid of it in $config['index_page'], codigniter cannot find my controller, which means that the mod_rewrite does not work. Thank you.

Comment: You missed trailing slash on RewriteBase. Do you have set your `base_url()`? Try with [this one](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your default controller in routes.php.

Comment: Got it fixed. Thank you.